# Listing Opportunities

Tags: opportunity, list

I've been trying to list opportunities in my account. There are only two opportunities created by me in salesforce. But while listing the same, more than 30 are shown in the list. I tried to filter using different methods(like by OwnerId and so). But none seems working.

CODE:

```
query = "SELECT Id, Name, AccountId FROM Opportunity"
    fileList = ""
    fileList = sf_api_call('/services/data/v40.0/query/', {'q': query})
    i =0
    for x in fileList['records']:
        folId = fileList['records'][i]["Id"]
        folName = fileList['records'][i]["Name"]
        AccountId = fileList['records'][i]["AccountId"]
        print(folName)
        i +=1
```

Any solutions??

Comment: This query definitely gets everything. You need to show an example of a query using a filter.

Comment: Visibility and ownership are very different, and they're also distinct from opportunities associated with an account. Your query will return the opportunities you can see, not those you own. Could you please try to clarify what you are aiming to achieve?

Comment: Hi @DavidReed, Thank you for the response.
I actually created two opportunities and I need to list only those two using query. But while using the above query, many opportunities are listed. I also tried using -
WHERE CreatedById = 'id'. Still its listing all the opportunities.

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox,
I tried using 
_query = "SELECT Id, Name, AccountId FROM Opportunity WHERE CreatedById =myId "_
Still its showing all the opportunities